# Can I do ios app development without Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur

I'm new to app development and I'm currently using macOS Big Sur. Unfortunately, I'm facing difficulties downloading Xcode since it's available for versions 13 and above. I've tried various solutions, but none of them seem to work. I'm now wondering if it's possible to proceed with app development without Xcode, especially since there isn't much information available about this topic.

I've attempted to download Xcode using various methods, but unfortunately, none of them have been successful. Additionally, I've tried to download the latest version of macOS, but that also didn't yield the desired results.

Comment: You should be able to download previous xcode versions there https://xcodereleases.com but you might need a "recent version" to publish apps...

Answer (score 0):

Probably some apps could be written.

My feeling is anything that needs a Capability or Entitlement would be too difficult.

Xcode actually does a lot of project/data/cert management on behalf of the coder.